# References on the impact of linearization in integer programming

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming, linearization

When dealing with non-linear integer programs, it is customary to linearize them. One example about the absolute value : [Mixed Integer linear programming - absolute value of a variable not involved n the objective function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1774275/mixed-integer-linear-programming-absolute-value-of-a-variable-not-involved-n-t/1790298#1790298)

Although many tricks can be found in the litterature to linearize, I couldn't find anything about the impact of linearization, which can be really bad. Indeed, it creates more variables, and tends to make the continuous relaxation of the MIP smaller.

Does anyone have some reference to share about it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In my opinion linearizations of absolute values are in general harmless. The main issue to watch out for is duplicating linear expressions which can add a large number of nonzeros. Here is an example of this from in a rather famous paper: [link](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2010/04/l1-portfolio-formulation.html).

Comment: If you need to add binary variables, the problem is really non-convex, so it is a hard problem to begin with.

Comment: Nice link, and I agree with the conclusion, a proper model is more important than a good solver. The addition of  (plenty of) binary variables is what worries me the most, especially the so called Glover technique for products